# Type list of selected items in a wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, selecteditem

I send the selected items to a specific command when the selection changes (each item is a class X)

I get them as object how can I convert it to a list?

I tried:

```
1. IList<x>  SelectedItemsList = obj as ObservableCollection<x>;

2. IList<x>  SelectedItemsList = obj as IList<x>;

3. List<x>  SelectedItemsList = obj as List<x>;
```

It did not help.

This type of list: `System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection` I want to convert it to my list: `ObservableCollection<x>/IList<x>/List<x>` (the ViewModel not recognized a list of controls of wpf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of the `SelectedItems` property is the non-generic [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx). You can't simply cast that to the generic [IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx).

You could however use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to get an `IEnumerable<x>` or a `List<x>`.

```
using System.Linq;

IList list = obj as IList;
IEnumerable<x> SelectedItemsList = list.Cast<x>();
// or 
List<x> SelectedItemsList = list.Cast<x>().ToList();
```