# Unable to cast .SelectedItems from DataGrid Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.5

Alright... it's friday, it's getting late, I'm a little frain bried...

Code:

```
public partial class SiteSelection : Window
{

    private IList<IISBrowser.IISSiteList> _siteList;

    public IList<IISBrowser.IISSiteList> SelectedItemsList { get; set; }

    public SiteSelection(IList<IISBrowser.IISSiteList> _sl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _siteList = _sl;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dg_Sites.ItemsSource = _siteList;
    }

    private void btnSelectSites_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItemsList = (IList<IISBrowser.IISSiteList>)dg_Sites.SelectedItems;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Populates a datagrid, where I can select items.  With a button (btnSelectSites)

I keep getting `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[Backup.S3.Store.IISBrowser+IISSiteList]'.`

And do not understand why...  it was my understanding that since I am setting this `IList<>` when applying to the ItemSource, that I would be returned the same data type..

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Already tried the solution here: [Type list of selected items in a wpf datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852371/type-list-of-selected-items-in-a-wpf-datagrid) which is similar to other solutions on here... none of which worked.

Comment: It may well be, however, I did try the solution in that question and the answer to it got me no-where.

Comment: I just fired up V.S. to test this myself. The last option of the linked answer should work for you. It's what @GrantWinney is doing in his answer here and I can confirm its working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this instead, casting the collection to the original type:

```
SelectedItemsList = dg_Sites.SelectedItems
                            .Cast<IISBrowser.IISSiteList>()
                            .ToList();
```

In the linked answer, `list` would be (in your case) the `dg_Sites.SelectedItems` collection.

You may also need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your class if it's not already there.

Comment: `Error 1 'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I'm a tool.  I needed to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: No biggee @GrantWinney my bad for removing it in the first place...  (sort and remove unused usings... LOL)